# How to perform multiple masks on demand on an Input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask

Iam trying to perform a mask on input using [jquery mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.com/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/), What I need to do is to perform two different masks:

US###-###-###-###-###-### this mask must be applied if the user is trying to type some numbers at first. (Which here I mean digit entry by #)

but if the user decided not to type any numerical at first I want to let him enter any kind of letters or unicod character or numbers (totally any character) after that

How should I perform such a mask?

Comment: Add a keyup event to the textbox and check if the input fiel's first character is a number or char, based on it add the masking dynamically to the control.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution may be using what is called in [the jQuery Mask Plugin's doc](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) by `On-the-fly mask change`, like following:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class="US" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off"/>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options =  {onKeyPress: function(us){
        var masks = ['CAAAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA', 'US000-000-000-000-000-000'];
        if(us.length){
            mask = (us[0].match(/\d/)) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
            $('.US').mask(mask, this);
        }
        $('.US').mask('AAAAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA', this);
    }};

    $('.US').mask('AAAAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA', options);
});
```

---

**Explanation**:

The problem you have with your input is that it uses the character S. Although, S already has a different signification in the plugin. According to Default Mask Legend:

```
S: Only A-Z and a-z characters.
```

So you have two options to resolve this: use a translation pattern, or override the default options in the "jquery.mask.js":

```
var custom_options = {
  byPassKeys: [8, 9, 37, 38, 39, 40],
  translation: {
                '0': {pattern: /\d/}, 
                '9': {pattern: /\d/, optional: true}, 
                '#': {pattern: /\d/, recursive: true}, 
                'A': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/}, 
                'S': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/}
            };
};
```

I choose the second one! I changed the 'S' by e.g 'C'. It could be another character.

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/vdyvh1d0/2/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!